# Smarty: check if variable is in array

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I'm using php with smarty.  In php I have two arrays:

```
$code = Array
(
    [n_id] => 1
    [t_code] => ABC123
    [t_description] => Test code
    [b_enabled] => Yes
    [n_type] => 3
    [dt_start] => 
    [dt_end] => 
    [n_min_req_gbp] => 0
    [n_min_req_usd] => 0
    [n_amount_gbp] => 
    [n_amount_usd] => 
    [n_max_overall_gbp] => 
    [n_max_overall_usd] => 
    [n_extra] => 6
    [b_reuse] => No
    [n_applications] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )
)
```

and

```
$all_application = Array
(
    [1] => New registration
    [2] => Mid-subscription upgrade
    [3] => Subscription renewal
    [4] => Additional purchase
)
```

Note that the second array may - and will - grow, this is the reference data, from which `n_applications` array field in the first array is built.  That is, the array in `n_applications` will contain a subset of keys from the `$all_applications` arrays.

Now, I'm assigning these two arrays into the template:

```
$template->assign('code', $code);
$template->assign('apps', $all_applications);
```

And in the template, I'm creating a form for editing the fields in the `$code` array.  Everything is working fine except the 'applications' selection.  I want to pre-select those apps that are already in the `n_applications` field.  So, in my template I have this:

```
<select name="c_apps[]" size="3" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    {foreach from=$apps key=k item=a}
        {assign var=v value=$k|@array_search:$code['n_applications']}
        <option value="{$k}"{if $v!==FALSE} selected="selected"{/if}>{$a|escape}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
```

However this doesn't work as expected - and ALL options end up being selected.  I tried using `in_array` function - but with the same result.  What's the best way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a bit of struggling in all possible directions, I finally managed to pull it off like this (smarty code only)

```
<select name="c_apps[]" size="3" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    {foreach from=$apps key=k item=a}
        {if @in_array($k, $code.n_applications)}
            {assign var=v value=true}
        {else}
            {assign var=v value=false}
        {/if}
        <option value="{$k}"{if $v} selected="selected"{/if}>{$a|escape}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
```

And this did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
<select name="c_apps[]" size="3" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    {foreach from=$apps key=k item=a}
        <option value="{$k}"{if in_array($k, $code.n_applications)} selected="selected"{/if}>{$a|escape}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, but the result was rather really bizzare, as a lot of something strange was added inside the <option> tag.

Comment: Well it should work. What was the result? And what version of Smarty do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar a few years back, and stumbled over the same logical challenge.

My solution was to modify the base array (in your case, `$all_applications`) while adding another key there (maybe `['opt_selected']`). I left the default value empty, and for the data I wanted to have selected, I've changed the value to, guess what, ...  `selected="selected"`.

This makes it rather easy for your Smarty template:

```
<option value="{$k}" {$a.opt_selected|default:''}>{$a|escape}</option>
```

It might not be the best solution, but it helps leaving alot of code out of the template where I usually don't want too much program logic.

**Update**

To counter having the HTML part in your php code, you might as well just flag the array:

```
$all_applications['opt_selected'] = 1
```

...and then arrange Smarty like this:

```
<option value="{$k}" {if $a.opt_selected eq '1'}selected="selected"{/if}>
  {$a|escape}
</option>
```

Comment: I suppose this makes the template a bit cleaner, but the PHP code a bit more dirty - and it puts HTML-specifics into the PHP, which is also not the best solution., but if it works...

Comment: I totally agree with you there. To clean this up, you might as well just set a flag and in your smarty template check the flag, I'll demonstrate in my main post.

Comment: I do get the idea.  One thing that worries me a bit about this approach is what I anticipate the my client to ask next, namely, these codes displayed in a table with in-place editing of each of them.  In this case, there will be multiple codes on the same page, each with its own array of applications - and one array of 'all_applications'.  Then it will get really messy...  Yet, thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, your array already has > 15 keys without my approach... one more or less doesn't make a big difference, does it!? ;-)

Comment: I see, add the full set of applications into each code, with the corresponding 'selected' ones marked...